# How to store files with random name on disk and only read those fit in a specific time period in python efficiently

Tags: python, django, storage

My program currently writes logs to disk. The log files are serialized objects having two fields: time and log message. The file names are random 32-char strings.

I also have a web UI in Django that let a user look at the logs, where the user can enter a duration (in seconds) and an endtime (any epoch timestamp), so all the logs from endtime-duration to endtime are displayed.

What I am currently doing:

1. Read all the logs from disk every time the user loads/refreshes the UI
2. Sort logs by time backwards
3. Have a for loop which spits logs, it continues when a log is newer than endtime, and breaks when first encountering a log that is older than endtime-duration

What I want to do:

1. Only read in the logs that the user is requesting, or at least do better than reading everything every time.

Constraints:

1. I cannot change the log file names, but I can store log files in different (sub)folders
2. No cache
3. Single threaded (logs can only be displayed after every log needed is read, no partial displays)

Thanks!

Comment: How long are the log files?

Comment: Is there any particular reason for storing individual files (especially with random names)? If not, this sounds like it could be easily solved with a simple database (like sqlite). Would storing the timestamps as the filename be an option..?

Comment: Each log file contains information about a run of an app, it contains app logs, app screenshots etc, database would be too much for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter files you read using modification date [`os.path.getmtime`](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/ctime_atime_mtime.html); reading first line of the file will help to determine whether it is in requested timeframe and worth reading. Additionaly, you can partition your log files by folders reflecting creation time, this will reduce amount of files to proceed.

```
>>> import os.path
>>> import time
>>> tmp_fname = '/tmp/tst'
>>> with open(tmp_fname, 'w') as f:
...     pass
...
>>> os.path.getctime('/tmp/tst')
1383596461.0
>>> time.ctime(os.path.getctime(tmp_fname))
'Mon Nov  4 20:21:01 2013' # changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Create folders by timestamp, write log like you normally do and then search folders by timestamp.

```
import time
import os

directory = str(time.time())
log_file = 'random_leters'
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
path = 'path_to_directory'
file_path = os.path.join(path, log_file)
#Some method of writing to logs
with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
    '''
    Write to log file
    '''

time_range = [start_time, finish_time]

for i in range(start_time, finish_time):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(path_to_logs, i)):
        '''
        Read Files
        '''
```

You will need to make your times iterable and create paths with them but this would work.